# How to scrape embedded links and tabular information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape information about the datasets available on [this website](https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset).

I want to collect the URLs to the resources and at least the title of the dataset.

Using [this resource](https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset/building-defects-complaint-data-2018) as an example, I want to capture the URL embedded in *"Go to resource"* and the title listed in the table: 
[image]

I have created a basic scraper, but it doesn't seem work:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = requests.get('https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset');
data_list=[]

if site.status_code is 200:
    content = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
    internals = content.select('.resource-url-analytics')
    for url in internals:
        title = internals.select=('.resource-url-analytics')[0].get_text()
        link = internals.select=('.resource-url-analytics')[0].get('href')
        new_data = {"title": title, "link": link}
        data_list.append(new_data)
    with open ('selector.csv','w') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = ["dataset", "link"], delimiter = ';')
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in data_list:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

I would like to write the output to a CSV with columns for the URLs and the titles.

This is an example of the desired output

[image: Desired output table]

Greatly appreciative for any assistance

Comment: how did you get second url via first url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [API for the datasets](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.7/api/) that will likely be the easiest way to do this.

In the meantime, here is how you can get the API links at id level from those pages and store the entire package info for all packages in one list, `data_sets`, and just the info of interest in another variable (`results`).  Be sure to review the API documentation in case there is a better method - for example, it would be nice if ids could be submitted in batches rather than per id.

Answer below is taking advantage of the endpoint detailed in the documentation which is used to get *a full JSON representation of a dataset, resource or other object*

Taking the current first result on landing page of:

**Vegetation of the Guyra 1:25000 map sheet VIS_ID 240**.

We want the last child `a` of parent `h3` with a parent having class `.dataset-item`. In the below, the spaces between selectors are [descendant combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

```
.dataset-item h3 a:last-child
```

You can shorten this to `h3 a:last-child`  for a small efficiency gain.

This relationship reliably selects all relevant links on page.

[image]

Continuing with this example, visiting that retrieved url for first listed item, we can find the id using api endpoint (which retrieves json related to this package), via an attribute=value selector with contains, *, operator. We know this particular api endpoint has a common string so we substring match on the `href` attribute value:

```
[href*="/api/3/action/package_show?id="]
```

The domain can vary and some retrieved links are relative so we have to test if relative and add the appropriate domain.

First page html for that match:

[image]

---

Notes:

1. `data_sets` is a list containing all the package data for each package and is extensive. I did this in case you are interest in looking at what is in those packages (besides reviewing the API documentation)
2. You can get total number of pages from soup object on a page via

```
   num_pages = int(soup.select('[href^="/data/dataset?page="]')[-2].text)
```

You can alter the loop for less pages.

1. Session object is used for [efficiency of re-using connection](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/). I'm sure there are other improvements to be made. In particular I would look for any method which reduced the number of requests (why I mentioned looking for a batch id endpoint for example).
2. There can be none to more than one resource url within a returned package. See example [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=773bc5675faa422d988902cef6b920f6). You can edit code to handle this.

---

Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlparse

json_api_links = []
data_sets = []

def get_links(s, url, css_selector):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    base = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=urlparse(url))
    links = [base + item['href'] if item['href'][0] == '/' else item['href'] for item in soup.select(css_selector)]
    return links

results = []
#debug = []
with requests.Session() as s:

    for page in range(1,2):  #you decide how many pages to loop
        
        links = get_links(s, 'https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset?page={}'.format(page), '.dataset-item h3 a:last-child')

        for link in links:
            data = get_links(s, link, '[href*="/api/3/action/package_show?id="]')
            json_api_links.append(data)
            #debug.append((link, data))
    resources = list(set([item.replace('opendata','') for sublist in json_api_links for item in sublist])) #can just leave as set
    
    for link in resources:
        try:
            r = s.get(link).json()  #entire package info
            data_sets.append(r)
            title = r['result']['title'] #certain items

            if 'resources' in r['result']:
                urls = ' , '.join([item['url'] for item in r['result']['resources']])
            else:
                urls = 'N/A'
        except:
            title = 'N/A'
            urls = 'N/A'
        results.append((title, urls))

    with open('data.csv','w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(['Title','Resource Url'])
        for row in results:
            w.writerow(row)
```

---

### All pages

(very long running so consider threading/asyncio):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlparse

json_api_links = []
data_sets = []

def get_links(s, url, css_selector):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    base = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=urlparse(url))
    links = [base + item['href'] if item['href'][0] == '/' else item['href'] for item in soup.select(css_selector)]
    return links

results = []
#debug = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    num_pages = int(soup.select('[href^="/data/dataset?page="]')[-2].text)
    links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.dataset-item h3 a:last-child')]

    for link in links:     
        data = get_links(s, link, '[href*="/api/3/action/package_show?id="]')
        json_api_links.append(data)
        #debug.append((link, data))
    if num_pages > 1:
        for page in range(1, num_pages + 1):  #you decide how many pages to loop
            
            links = get_links(s, 'https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset?page={}'.format(page), '.dataset-item h3 a:last-child')

            for link in links:
                data = get_links(s, link, '[href*="/api/3/action/package_show?id="]')
                json_api_links.append(data)
                #debug.append((link, data))
        
        resources = list(set([item.replace('opendata','') for sublist in json_api_links for item in sublist])) #can just leave as set
 
        for link in resources:
            try:
                r = s.get(link).json()  #entire package info
                data_sets.append(r)
                title = r['result']['title'] #certain items

                if 'resources' in r['result']:
                    urls = ' , '.join([item['url'] for item in r['result']['resources']])
                else:
                    urls = 'N/A'
            except:
                title = 'N/A'
                urls = 'N/A'
            results.append((title, urls))

    with open('data.csv','w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(['Title','Resource Url'])
        for row in results:
            w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and code. This is incredibly insightful and helpful.

Comment: There is some room for improvement but give it a go and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: It works brilliantly, does exactly what I need :) Would it be simple enough to add an additional column to pick up the data portal information? In the example you provided, there is a class for ' .data-portal="SEED" ' Could I add that in as an extra variable in the get_links function, or does it require its own standalone function? I would like to output the data portal information for each resource where that class contains a text string.

Comment: Can you provide an example url and indication of what should be retrieved please?

Comment: Sure. So this [url](https://datasets.seed.nsw.gov.au/dataset/new-england-and-gumbaynggir-national-parks-vegetation-sites-2000-vis_id-1427f50e2) should return "SEED", and this [url](https://www.planningportal.nsw.gov.au/opendata/dataset/environmental-planning-instrument-height-of-buildings-hob) should return "ePlanning". I've [highlighted](https://imgur.com/a/lcl60Jt) the element I'd like to capture, specifically the '.data-portal=' field. Basically what I'm trying to pick up is the "from [portal]" entry that you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/3eADxEi) in the catalogue, where applicable.

Comment: Very helpful. I will have a look tonight.

Comment: [Here's an example of the output I'm after](https://imgur.com/a/6UDSdco)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very appreciative :)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity use selenium package:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

# initialise browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset')

# find all elements by xpath
get_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/section/div/ul/li/div/h3/a[2]')

# collect data
data = []
for item in get_elements:
    data.append((item.text, item.get_attribute('href')))
```

Output:

```
('Vegetation of the Guyra 1:25000 map sheet VIS_ID 240', 'https://datasets.seed.nsw.gov.au/dataset/vegetation-of-the-guyra-1-25000-map-sheet-vis_id-2401ee52')
('State Vegetation Type Map: Riverina Region Version v1.2 - VIS_ID 4469', 'https://datasets.seed.nsw.gov.au/dataset/riverina-regional-native-vegetation-map-version-v1-0-vis_id-4449')
('Temperate Highland Peat Swamps on Sandstone (THPSS) spatial distribution maps...', 'https://datasets.seed.nsw.gov.au/dataset/temperate-highland-peat-swamps-on-sandstone-thpss-vegetation-maps-vis-ids-4480-to-4485')
('Environmental Planning Instrument - Flood', 'https://www.planningportal.nsw.gov.au/opendata/dataset/epi-flood')

and so on
```